# Scikit Learn: Skewed Average Precision Report

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, metrics, average-precision

I'm using scikit-learn to perform binary classification, however the labels are not evenly distributed throughout the dataset. For cases where I'm interested in predicting the minority class, I have some concerns about the average precision metric provided by `metrics.average_precision_score`. When I run the experiments, and print a classification report I see good performance on precision overall, but this is clearly from the model doing well on predicting the majority class, something like this:

```
                     precision    recall    f1-score    support
label of interest    0.24         0.67      0.35        30
non-label            0.97         0.81      0.88        300
```

The `average precision` is then reported as somewhere around `0.9752`. This average precision score is clearly being reported with respect to the majority class, which isn't really the class I'm interested in identifying. Is there some way to modify the `metrics.average_precision_score` function to report the metric with respect to the minority class of interest? Any insight would be greatly appreciated - thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a solution after much tinkering. I'd been using the preprocessing tool `LabelEncoder()` to automatically encode the labels for the training and test sets. I'm performing binary classification, so the labels just need an encoding of `0` or `1`. However, when doing this, the function automatically encodes the majority class as `1` and the minority class as `0`. For cases where I'm interested in predicting the minority class (which is often) this skews the report of the `average precision` function in favor of *whatever* the majority class is, whether I'm interested in predicting this or not.

This led me to ask another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26890477/flipping-zeroes-and-ones-in-one-dimensional-numpy-array) about "flipping" the `0` and `1` values in the array that my labels are assigned to and, lo and behold, it's working. So, the bottom line is to just be more intentional to make sure that the class I'm interested in predicting is *always* encoded as `1`, and making sure the other class is encoded as `0`.

Answer (score 3):

You can get set `average=None` to get per-class average precision scores ([docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html#sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score)). Keep in mind, though, that the average precision scores take into account all possible thresholds, while the classification report only shows one threshold, which is likely biased towards the majority class.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, @Andreas. One question: if I'm implementing this correctly, then I should have two average precision scores for each held out validation I perform, is that correct? When I run my script currently I'm still only seeing one average precision score. I'm just running this portion as `print metrics.average_precision_score(test_labels, predicted_labels, average=None)` in my current script. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Hum, sorry, I just realized my original answer was misleading. That works only if you give it a decision function of size ``(n_samples, 2)``. Whoops. You can just flip the two classes, though (pass ``1-y_true`` and ``-decision_function`` to ``average_precision_score``).