# Flipping zeroes and ones in one-dimensional NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a one-dimensional NumPy array that consists of zeroes and ones like so:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

I'd like a quick way to just "flip" the values such that zeroes become ones, and ones become zeroes, resulting in a NumPy array like this:

```
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Is there an easy one-liner for this? I looked at the `fliplr()` function, but this seems to require NumPy arrays of dimensions two or greater. I'm sure there's a fairly simple answer, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **Note:** Python has bools, and so does NumPy. Use them, not `0`/`1`, or `'0'`/`'1'`.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

There must be something in your Q that i do not understand...

Anyway

```
In [2]: from numpy import array

In [3]: a = array((1,0,0,1,1,0,0))

In [4]: b = 1-a

In [5]: print a ; print b
[1 0 0 1 1 0 0]
[0 1 1 0 0 1 1]

In [6]:
```

Comment: Nice and simple indeed, +1. The only potential issue is that it isn't easy to do in-place. Just because of that I prefer using bitwise XOR, `a = a ^ 1`, which lets you do `a ^= 1`.

Comment: Why choose this over `numpy.logical_not()`, or `~`? Especially since OP is clearly using boolean values.

Answer (score 15):

A sign that you should probably be using a boolean datatype

```
a = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=np.bool)
# or
b = ~a
b = np.logical_not(a)
```

Answer (score 7):

another superfluous option:

```
numpy.logical_not(a).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
answer = numpy.ones_like(a) - a
```

Comment: (actually @gboffi 's answer is better)

Answer (score 1):

I also found a way to do it:

```
In [1]: from numpy import array

In [2]: a = array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

In [3]: b = (~a.astype(bool)).astype(int)


In [4]: print(a); print(b)
[1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

Still, I think that @gboffi's answer is the best. I'd have upvoted it but I don't have enough reputation yet :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If a question is already answered - especially if it's from 3 years ago(!) - please don't add a solution that you know is inferior than the one that was selected. Good luck!