# Invert 0 and 1 in a binary array

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a function in Numpy to invert 0 and 1 in a binary array?
If

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1])
```

I would like to get:

```
b = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

I use:

```
b[a==0] = 1
b[a==1] = 0
```

but maybe it already exist something in Numpy to do this.

Comment: you can simply do `b=1-a`.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728708/inverting-a-numpy-boolean-array-using

Comment: **Note:** Python has bools, and so does NumPy. Use them, not `0`/`1`, or `'0'`/`'1'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flipping zeroes and ones in one-dimensional NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26890477/flipping-zeroes-and-ones-in-one-dimensional-numpy-array)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

you can simply do:

```
In[1]:b=1-a
In[2]:b
Out[2]: array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```

or

```
In[22]:b=(~a.astype(bool)).astype(int)
Out[22]: array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 15):

A functional approach:

```
>>> np.logical_not(a).astype(int)
array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3, suppose

```
a = [1]
a.append(a[0]^1)
print(a)
```

Output will be:

```
[1,0]
```

Thus if you apply a loop:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    a.append(a[i]^1)
```

all the elements of the list will be inverted.

Comment: Hi @WasimKhan, thank you for your answer. Could you please improve clarity with [markdown editing](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)?

Answer (score 1):

Another funny approach:

```
b = 2**a % 2
```

It works since 2**0 = 1.

Comment: This is interesting for cases where the numpy array is not boolean and instead are floats.