# Optimized way to split the <numpy ndarray> to two columns in Python

Tags: python, numpy

Let's consider the following **numpy ndarray**,

```
[[0],
 [0],
 [0],
 [0],
 [0],
 [1],
 [0]]
```

I want to make it to two column like,

```
    A     B
0   1     0
1   1     0
2   1     0
3   1     0
4   1     0
5   0     1
6   1     0
```

Now, I'm doing in the following way,

```
a = []
b = []
for i in lb_results:
    if i == 0:
        a.append(1)
        b.append(0)
    else:
        a.append(0)
        b.append(1)

lb_results = np.column_stack((a, b))
print(lb_results)
```

but I'm expecting something **more optimized** way, (less number of code lines are better, without using much more loops)
Any suggestions would be grateful, Thanks.

Comment: There's no need for any loops, just create a second 1D array using the methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26890477/flipping-zeroes-and-ones-in-one-dimensional-numpy-array) and then stack (all you're doing is flipping 0's and 1's)

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks, It's also working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use xor like so:

```
>>> c = (np.c_[:7] == 5).astype(int)
>>> c
array([[0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [1],
       [0]])
>>> c ^ (1, 0)
array([[1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0]])
```

I guess this is about as short as it gets ;-)

The magic behind this is [`numpy` broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Briefly, xor operator `^` gets applied to each pair between an element of the column `c` and an element of the the 1D sequence `(1, 0)` leading to the full "xor table" between the two.

Comment: Maybe unnecessarily short... I would suggest `np.column_stack((np.logical_not(b), b))`

Comment: @paul Thanks, I think, it would be difficult, if once we don't know the index of 1's (i.e, in your example it is '5')

Comment: @JaiK It works for any column `c` consisting of ones and zeros. The first line is just a shortcut to recreate your example vector. Please try it out: create a different `c` and do `c ^ (1, 0)`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Yes, Paul. Good, Working nice.. sorry, I understood mistakenly.